# How to efficiently handle a large number of Socket.IO Rooms in a Chat Application

Tags: performance, optimization, socket.io, chat

I am developing a chat application similar to Facebook Messenger and am trying to design a feature for real-time group message updates. To more detail, when you open Messenger, you see a list of group chats. I am wondering how to receive messages in real-time from a group chat that has not been active for a long time.

Assume my system have 1M users and each user have 5000 group chats. Socket.io is used

Solution:

Naive way: each user have to join 5000 rooms => 5 billion subscribe are created => performance, resource issue

My way: Each user have 1 default room then new message will be emit to each member's default room

I wonder if there is any way to handle this issue better and how big tech company handle this problem.